# Bourbaki Algebraic Structures Question 4.10 [conditions under which preimage of canonical quotient is commutative]

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups

Question: Let $\mathrm H$ be a normal subgroup of a group $\mathrm G$ contained in the center of $\mathrm G$. Show that if $\mathrm {G/H}$ is a monogenous group $\mathrm G$ is commutative.

*(See the answer below for an attempt.)*

Comment: If, as it seems apparent, you are asking for solution verification, please use the relevant tag.

Comment: I'm puzzled, in the case of question 4.10 the solution is apparent. The help desk you mentioned says that answering your own questions is encouraged. I don't think I was asking for solution verification in this particular instance.
https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer#:~:text=If%20you%20have%20more%20than,own%20question%20at%20any%20time.

Comment: Do you have any tips on how to obtain a solution to part (b) of question 4.8? I'm very curious about this structure and it comes up again in question 13 in the form of an equivalence condition.

Comment: Yes, answering your own question is fine; but you are describing this as an "attempt", so  it soundsl like you are not certain you are providing a correct answer. That suggests, to *me* at any rate, that you are seeking feedback on your *attempted* solution, and thus that "solutions verification" might be an appropraite tag

Comment: P.S. I really don't love your use of `mathrm`. Not really sure why you think you should type the entirety of the math in roman font, overruling MathJax (and LaTeX's) standard behavior.

Comment: Oh I see. If you check the edit history the sentence "See the answer below for an attempt." was inserted by user Shaun. My initial post just contained Bourbaki Algebraic Structures Question 4.10

Comment: P.P.S. Though it worked for you this time, please do not use comments in one question to try to call attention to an **unrelated** question; that's not what comments are for.

Comment: I apologize for the Roman font. It isn't fun to typeset either, but Bourbaki uses this font in their book and I do not wish to be ahistorical. I do worry about this given that in an edit a user commented that it bothered them.

Comment: If your intent is to faithfully copy Bourbaki even down to the typeface, then you are failing: although Bourbaki uses roman typeface for uppercase math symbols, lower case is usually typeset in italic; for example, your Question 4.8 in my edition (Springer softcover 2nd printing 1989) has $\{e\}$ for the identity, where you typed $\{\mathrm{e}\}$. tbh, "I do not wish to be ahistorical" seems, at best, a rather weird excuse, not to use rather stronger adjectives. I would suggest that you drop the silliness.

Comment: I have consulted my volume more carefully and you are correct. Apologies for being obtuse. Maybe I should relax this inconsequential deference to empire

Comment: I, like most people I know, would have some trouble thinking of, say, $g$ and $\mathrm{g}$ as representing the same object: I would assume the distinction in typeface represents a distinction in object. For the same reason, I would be very careful to see whether $H$ and $\mathrm{H}$ are meant to be the same thing (and would assume *not*). That means that you are *forcing* those who reply to you to either use *different* notation than you are using, or to adopt the idiosyncratic use of typefaces you are using. This is not a problem for Bourbaki, because they are writing everything.

Comment: Interesting that objects can change as the letter shears. I was unfamiliar with this custom. I will use MathJax standard.

Answer (score 0):

By hypothesis $\mathrm {g,g' \in G}$ implies $\mathrm {gH = (xH)^{n} = x^nH}$. Hence $\mathrm {g = x^nh_1}$ and $\mathrm {g' = x^mh_2}$. We have $\mathrm {x^nx^m = x^mx^n}$, members of $\mathrm H$ are central, it follows that $\mathrm {gg' = g'g}$.

Comment: Yes, correct (if you are asking for a solution verification).